# FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal - while building this syntax facing problem

Tags: python

Creating image using below commands in Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add --no-cache git make musl-dev go python3.6
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi
RUN sed -i 's/\(def in_container():\)/\1\n    return False/g' /usr/lib64/python3/site-packages/rhsm/config.py
```

Using above ubi version its able to build the docker image, but the issue is when i change to the different version ubi-minimal, it could not able to generate the image.

the error is:

```
=> ERROR [stage-1 4/4] RUN sed -i 's/\(def in_container():\)/\1\n    return False/g' /usr/lib64/python3/site-packages/rhsm/config.py                    0.4s
```

It would be great if someone could help me on above issue. Thanks!